# NFL division with all teams having a losing or winning record

Tags: trivia, american-football, history, nfl

I'm wondering if there has been any division in the modern day NFL history where all teams finished the regular season with winning or losing record. Even though this might not be so probable, it is definitely possible.

This question is motivated by what's been happening this year (2014) in the NFL. All teams in the AFC North (Cincinnati, Pittsburgh, Baltimore and Cleveland) have winning record as of week 12; and teams in NFC South (Atlanta, New Orleans, Carolina, Tampa Bay) all have losing record! at the end of week 12, the worst record in AFC North was 7-4 which is better than the best record in NFC South at 4-7.

**UPDATE:**

- The 2014 NFC South's champion is Carolina Panthers with a losing record of 7-8-1.
- 2014 AFC North did not have all team with winning record as Cleveland Brown finished at 7-9

Comment: @Joe You fixed the problem twice in the body, but missed it in the title.

Comment: It could even happen in the NFC West, The Rams are on a hot streak and need to win out, the cards are on the wane, the Rams should beat the Giants but they would still need to win (or Tie) in Seattle for a winning record.
The 49ers would also need to win two of there last three and they have a tough run in so not likely but certainly possible (bit of a change from 2010!).

Comment: *losing* not *loosing*.  *lose* not *loose*.  Loose means "not tight", like when your pants are too loose and fall down.  "Lose" means "not win", like when you are the Chicago Bears.

Comment: I'd answer this question with an update, but I don't have the reputation. We almost had a 6-10 division winner this year. It would've been the New York Giants. If only the Eagles had beaten Washington.

Comment: In 2022, NFC East's lowest-scoring team was the Wahington Commanders, with an 8-8-1 record... Therefore, depending on if winning includes .500, this could be your answer...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the NFC West had all teams finish with a losing record in 2010.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFC_West) mentions this:

> In 2010, the NFC West became the first division in NFL history to have a champion with a losing record, after the 2010 Seattle Seahawks won the division title with a record of 7-9.

I also found this [heavy.com article](http://heavy.com/sports/2014/11/could-the-afc-north-make-nfl-history-in-2014/) that says the following regarding the current 2014 season:

> At the unofficial midpoint of the 2014 NFL season, the AFC North Division has all four teams sporting winning records: Cincinnati (5-2-1), Pittsburgh (6-3), Cleveland (5-3) and Baltimore (5-4). If all four remain above .500 at the end of the season, it would be the first time in NFL history that all of the teams from one division finished with a winning record.

That means no NFL division has ever had all of its teams finish with a winning record.

In 2014, the NFC South had all of its teams finish with a losing record.  The Carolina Panthers won the division with a 7-8-1 record, as mentioned in [this article](http://www.charlotteobserver.com/2014/12/28/5411641/carolina-panthers-obliterate-atlanta.html#.VKCi61fmA):

> Carolina (7-8-1) won its fourth in a row to join the 2010 Seattle Seahawks (7-9) as the only teams to capture a division title with a losing record.

In 2020, the NFC East had all of its teams finish with a losing record: Washington (7-9), New York (6-10), Dallas (6-10), Philadelphia (4-11-1).

Comment: Please update your answer to include 2020 NFC East

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest a division has come to all of the teams having a winning record was in [2002](https://www.pro-football-reference.com/years/2002/) when the AFC East and West all had a non-losing record. The Jets, Patriots, Dolphins and Broncos all finished 9-7, the Bills, Chargers and Chiefs were 8-8 and the Raiders were 11-5.

Comment: Hey Scott, welcome to Sports SE. Please provide some sources to your answre.